# Issue in printing Char Array() which is converted from String

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, console.writeline

Got stuck with this.. can you please explain what is happening in it? or give me any link!

```
String s1="C# Example";
Char[] s3 = s1.ToCharArray();

Console.WriteLine("S3 : {0}",s3);
```

I want to display the  Character which is converted. Output displayed is **System.Char[]**. Now i need to do some changes, but what is that ?

It is possible in two ways.

1) I need to Change it to String, before i'm going to Print.

Or

2) I need to print it with Char by defining the index, (i.e) s3[0];

Am i correct. Anything More?

Comment: Depends upon what you wanted to display.

Comment: don't you think you need to loop through the char-array to display it on console!

Comment: Now i edited the question, Just say me? @SriramSakthivel

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do - your post talks about "display the Character", but title says "printing Char Array()"... Seems like `Console.WriteLine(s1);` should give you good readable result...

Comment: Sample input, sample output would help us all

Comment: If you need to display it as a string, then why you converter it to char array? Just use `Console.WriteLine(s1);`, or loop the char array and display each character.

Comment: just leave that String, i want to print the Char Array. When i give Console.WriteLine(s3). It is doing good, But If i use Any sentence inside writeline, what i need to do? @SriramSakthivel

Comment: Why so many down votes??? its valid question for as a SO question.

Comment: Giving **down vote** is Easy than **answering**!

Comment: Still not sure, how exactly you want your output to look like. If you just want the whole content of the `char[]`, you could use this [String Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) to get a "new" string. Or if you want separators maybe this [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd988350.aspx) overload.

Comment: Don't worry @Corak i have already got the solution, i asked the ways it can be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Solution A:***

If you want to display the characters individually on console then you need to get each character separately and display it using a loop.

```
foreach(char ch in  s3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("S3 : {0}", ch);
}
```

*or*, using for-loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < s3.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("S3 : {0}", s3[i]);
}
```

***Solution B :***
There's anbther way that I prefer which might not be helpful for you but for those who always looks into better solutions it can be an option also.

Use [***Extension methods***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx),

Add this class with the extension method in your solution,

```
public static class DisplayExtension 
{
    public static string DisplayResult(this string input)
    {
        var resultString = "";
        foreach (char ch in input.ToCharArray())
        {
            resultString += "S3 : " + ch.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        return resultString;
    }
}
```

And call the *DisplayResult()* extension method from your program like this,

```
Console.WriteLine(s1.DisplayResult());
```

This will give you the same result but extend the re-usability of your code without writing the for loop for all the repeated situation.

Comment: Why you are using **foreach** can you display it without foreach? @Ashad

Comment: @Balaji, To loop through the character array (s3). You can also use for-loop instead of foreach.

Comment: and also `do-while`, `while-do`, `go-to`, recursion... did I forget anything?

Answer (score 4):

The explanation of what happens:

- `Console.WriteLine("{0}", s3)` calls `s3.ToString()`.

  - Because WriteLine() calls ToString() on each argument
- Method `ToString()` isn't overridden in type `System.Array` so `Object.ToString()` is called.

  - Because Char[] is System.Array and all types inherit from Systen.Object.
- Which is equivalent to `s3.GetType().ToString()` and outputs `System.Char[]`.

  - Because this is the default implementation. Subtypes can override it. For instance, System.String does, StringBuilder too.

Answer (score 2):

**Good** answers so far, and **great** explanation from *@abatishchev* on why `WriteLine()` prints System.Char[]

How ever I would like to add an additional solution, because using loops inside your `WriteLine()` will look confusing and its not very pleasing to the eye. For better readability you can use `new string()`

In this example it would look like this:

```
String s1="C# Example";
Char[] s3 = s1.ToCharArray();

Console.WriteLine("S3 : {0}",new string(s3));
```

Comment: This sounds like the obvious solution; maybe it was not available at the time of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("S3 : {0}",s3);
```

gives result s3.ToString() which results `System.Char[]`

Instead create a for loop like:

```
Console.Write("S3 :"); 
for(int i=0; i<s3.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(s3[i]);
}
```

which gives desired output

Answer (score 1):

```
char [] str = new char[20];
```

Suppose str is the character array, and we need to display it. Do the following (provided you enter something in the str using loop):

```
Console.WriteLine("The string is: {0}", string.Join("",str));
```

Here, each character in str is joined and displayed.